# What is "analytic vector for closed operator"?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, definition

I need the defenition of "analytic vector of closed operator that acts on Hilbert space". I cant find it in google and in my textbooks (Khelemsky "Lectures And Exercises on Functional Analysis"), I need to source where I can read the definition.

Comment: Never heard of. Which page is it?

Comment: I first read that you got it from that book you cite. Sorry. Where did you read this term?

Comment: It is from dissertation of Ukrainian mathematician (on Ukrainian language), so, I dont think that refer on it will be very interesting. I thought that it is general terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a Google search I found this: [Analytic Vectors (Nelson's Theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853787/analytic-vectors-nelsons-theorem) . You find the definition in answer 2.

Comment: Thanks! I think that is exactly what I need.