# How to find the self-adjoint extension of an unbounded symmetric operator?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

I have an unbounded symmetric operator, and I would like to find its self-adjoint extension if possible. First off, what properties does such an operator need in order to have a self-adjoint extension, and what are the steps I need to take to get this extension?

For concreteness, the operator I am looking at is an infinite dimensional matrix $M_{nm}$ acting on $l^2$ which reads

$$M_{nm}=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}\Big((4n+3)\delta_{nm}+2n\delta_{n-1m}+(2n+3)\delta_{n+1m}\Big)$$

This is symmetric with respect to the inner product $(u,v)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u^*_nv_n$.

Comment: There is [Carleman's test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1410755/252672). How fast does the part with the !!s grow?

Comment: @KeithMcClary The double factorials grow like $\sim \sqrt{\pi n}$.

Comment: Carleman won't work then. There is another test for semibounded operators with growth $~n^2$.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Where would I go to find such tests?

Comment: Eqn. 6 on p. 26 [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123672900559) has the corresponding condition for semibounded Jacobi matrices.

Comment: It is stated on p.25 #4 of Akhiezer's book "The Classical Moment Problem ...".

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no clue these matrices are called Jacobi matrices, and that there is already a wealth of research on them. I have a lot of reading to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121232/discussion-between-fewfew4-and-keith-mcclary).